# What is difference between abstract class with all abstract methods and interface(not technically)

Tags: java, oop, types, interface, abstract-class

I've been wondering what is the difference between them? Is it only in this: *abstract class* declares **what an object is** and *interface* says **what object can do**? Or there is something more deeper? Thanks.

Comment: In Java, an abstract class never has only abstract methods, because it subclasses Object. An interface is usually a better choice, because subclasses can extend at most one class, but implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: also you can extends only one abstract class and you can implements multiple interfaces...

Comment: That's a pretty deep difference if you ask me. And a lot of practical differences spawn from it, like you can directly implement multiple interfaces but not extend multiple classes, or you can declare fields in classes and so on.

Comment: The purpose of an abstract class is to root a single implementation hierarchy, whereas an interface declares a type and defines its promises and demands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "abstract class declares what an object is" refers to the rule that says that a class may inherit from a base class if it has an "is a" relationship to the base class.  So, a `Sedan` may inherit from `Car` because a `Sedan` "is a" `Car`.  But that's only part of the story.  Usually, we define abstract base classes to inherit from when we want the abstract base class to contain some functionality that restricts derived classes in what they can do, often by exposing `final` methods which cannot be overridden.  So, a hypothetical mail delivery abstract base class may offer a `public final prepareAndSend()` method which invokes abstract overridables on itself called `stuffEnvelope()`, `lickEnvelope()`, `mailEnvelope()`, in that order.  The derived class may override those methods, but it has no power to change the order in which they will be invoked because `prepareAndSend()` is final.  You can't impose such restrictions with interfaces.

Interfaces, on the other hand, describe "capabilities" or "aspects" that an object may have.  An object may have many different capabilities, so it may implement many interfaces.

Note that it may *seem* that the "is a" relationship *can* apply to interfaces, but it either only happens in certain contrived examples, or it is an illusion caused by the liberal syntax of the English language; it is not generalizable, in many cases it is not even factual, and that's the reason why there is no rule that says that an object should have an "is a" relationship with each interface that it implements.

So, someone may of course make an "ICar" interface, there is nothing wrong with that, in which case there will inevitably be something that "is a Car", but what you are more likely to see is interfaces like "IDrivable", "IInsurable", "ITaxable", "IFuelConsumer", etc. all of which describe traits.  The fact that you can then say "a car is a taxable" is a fluke of the English language; a car does not *actually* bear an "is a" relationship with "taxable" because "taxable" is not even a thing.  So then, whoever came up with that "ICar" usually just meant it as a convenience to combine all the characteristics of a car into one common interface.

Comment: The "is a" relationship also applies to interfaces. If Sedan implements the interface ICar, directly or indirectly, then a Sedan is-a ICar.

Comment: @AndyThomas of course we have entered the realm of philosophy here. See edit.  I know you might disagree, but that's life. Advanced level disclosure: an object "is a" interface only for those rare, special interfaces that expose some sort of destructor.

Comment: Um, no ... the IS-A relationship does not depend on private implementation details. It's a relationship among types, dependent on the public behavior, not the private implementation. In Java, all inheritance relationships should express an ISA relationship, regardless whether the language classifies those types as classes or interfaces -- they should all satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle. If Fox inherits from Animal, it ISA Animal, regardless whether it is inheriting an implementation or not. Finally, as an observation, this answer seems oriented more towards C++ than Java.

Comment: Isn't "IS A" relationship occur when class inherits interface of other type? By creating subtype, I mean.

Comment: @Twinkle_Monkey I think so.  But apparently we have lack of consensus on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it can have fields, whether it can have a constructor, whether any of those methods can be protected/package-private/private, whether subtypes can inherit from other abstract classes/interfaces...that about covers it.

Comment: "... that about covers it", except for the minor question of which serves what purposes. All "what" and no "why".

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there are no pure abstract classes. A class that declares only abstract methods has concrete methods also, because it is a subclass -- directly or indirectly -- of the concrete Object class.

An interface is a better choice for defining an abstract API. Java allows classes to extend at most one class, but implement multiple interfaces.

From the Java tutorial [Abstract Methods and Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) (line breaks added):

> However, with abstract classes, you can declare fields that are not static and final, and define public, protected, and private concrete methods.
>
> With interfaces, all fields are automatically public, static, and final, and all methods that you declare or define (as default methods) are public.
>
> In addition, you can extend only one class, whether or not it is abstract, whereas you can implement any number of interfaces.

The tutorial also recommends cases when an abstract class or interface are desirable. Paraphrased, it recommends abstract classes when you want to share code or non-static, non-final fields, or use access qualifiers other than public. Usually none of these will apply to a pure abstract class.

It recommends interfaces when you want to specify an API that may be implemented by multiple unrelated classes, or want to take advantage of multiple inheritance of interface types.